# Grub not Showing Windows 7

Tags: grub-legacy

I recently installed Ubuntu to my harddrive and now I can only boot to Ubuntu, Windows 7 does not show up, please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Tristin! Can you try running [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: Yes I have tried, It did not work.

Comment: Can you please include **everything you've tried** in the question?  This is to avoid people from taking the time and suggesting/answering the question, only to find out that you've already done it. You can always [edit] your question using the `edit` link right underneath it. Anywho, when you tried boot repair, it should have created a log file containing information and gave you a link. Can you please provide that link?

Answer (score 0):

Is this Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, or 13.04?

Anyhow, open a terminal using `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`T` and run this command:

```
sudo update-grub | tee ~/update-grub.txt
```

You will need to type in your password. After that runs, try restarting. If it still doesn't work, give us the contents of the file called `update-grub.txt` located in your home directory.

Comment: That didnt work but thanks anyway, and I have nothing in that file